# I cant deploy my dispatch config file to App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I'm having trouble with deploying my `dispatch.yaml` file to App Engine, using the following command (as described in [the doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/dispatch-yaml)):

```sh
gcloud app deploy displatch.yaml --project [my-project] --account [my-email@gmail.com]
```

`dispatch.yaml` looks like this:

```yaml
dispatch:
  - url: something.mycustomdomain.com/*
    service: something
```

This used to work fine, but now I'm getting this error:

```
Unexpected attribute 'dispatch' for object of type AppInfoExternal.
in "/home/bgirschig/Documents/projects/offensive culture/WEB/website/displatch.yaml"
```

I had made a change to the file, but reverting it to its previous state does not sovle the issue.

I've tried:

- Updating the gcloud components (to Google Cloud SDK 303.0.0): didn't help
- Looking for the issue on stack: found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24516571/how-to-solve-an-error-on-gae-for-unexpected-attribute-dispatch-for-object-of) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534418/invalid-dispatch-configuration/36208733#36208733) but they are really old and seem obsolete (using appcfg.py)
- Looking for the issue on Google: Same as above (old and obsolete answers)

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could delete my question...

This is a simple typo:
My file was called `displatch.yaml` instead of `dispatch.yaml`.

It looks like gcloud uses the name of the file to decide what to do with it.

Comment: seems like this is not an issue for you anymore, however, you can delete your question if you consider it's necessary https://www.bleepingworld.com/delete-question-on-stack-overflow/

Comment: Thanks, but now I think this question and answer might be useful to someone: The fact that 'dispatch.yaml' is a special filename is not entirely clear in the documentation. Before this, I assumed the name of the file was irrelevant (like for app.yaml) and the deploy script would figure out what to do from the content. Turns out it's not the case

Comment: +1 to this answer. i originally named my file staging.dispatch.yaml, which was not accpeted. Renaming to dispatch.yaml.com fixed it.

Comment: please don't delete your question! this just saved me hours...